# Python: Trying to get user input from moving outside border around on business card

Tags: python, border, whitespace, indentation, quotes

```
first_name = input("What is your first name?")

last_name = input("What is your last name?")

phone_number = input("What is your phone #?")

one = ('|')
two = ('|')
print('Here is your business card...')

business_card = """
+------------------------------------------------+
|    |                                           |
|   -|          %s, %s                           %s
|  --|          Tribute Liabilities Associate    |
| ---|          Parasail Capital                 |
| ---------                                      |
|  -------      4 Hunger Plaza                   |
|               STE 1400                         |
|               District 12, Panem 00012         | 
|                                                |
| Work: %s  @: champ@parasail.com                %s
+------------------------------------------------+""" % (first_name, last_name, one , phone_number, two)



print (business_card)

print('Here is your business card...')
```

Trying to get first/last name and phone number in on the business card without moving the border. Because of the white space that a name and/or the phone number produces it automatically moves the border(either left or right).... any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If you use the format() string method you can tell it how much white space to place on either side of the string you are inputting.

Here's the documentation for the mini-language involved in format(): 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec

So when you input a name  you would do something like `"{:15}".format(name)` where `15` is the number of spaces you are allowing it to fill (inputs default to left aligned). This gives you more control than `"%s" % (name)` and allows for easier formatting.

In general the format() documentation will be a wealth of information on how to dynamically format your strings.